# login page problem in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I'm getting the same problem, one of stackoverflow which is:

```
if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    //const char *sql ="select Username@'%@',Password@'%@' from userinformation";
    NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * from UserInformation where UserName='%@' and Password='%@' ",Username.text,Password.text];
    sqlite3_stmt *selectSatement;

    // Here i am getting the problem.Im not sure why sqlite3_prepare_v2 ins't meeting SQLITE_OK 
    if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &selectSatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        //-------------------------------------
        //Loop all the 
        NSString *user1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectSatement, 0)];
        NSLog(@"%@",user1);
    }
}
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: if you open the database, you should also close it by using sqlite3_close(database)

I wrote in the code below an assert-statement, which will tell you, if something is wronmg with your query. Further on you might get an error, if your password or username is for some reason "nil", that's why I adapted the way you set the username and password a bit. If the value does not exist, its "0"

```
if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    char *errorMsg;

    NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM UserInformation WHERE UserName=\"%@\" and Password =\"%@\"", Username.text, Password.text];
    if (sqlite3_exec (database, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errorMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error selecting data: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *user1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:((char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0) ? (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0) : (char *)"0")];
        NSString *password1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:((char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1) ? (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1) : (char *)"0")];
        NSLog(@"%@: %@",user1,password1);
    }
    [sql release];
}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

What you should also keep in mind is, that the database should exist at the intended path, by calling for example the following method

```
-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath]) return;
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
    [fileManager release];
}
```

Comment: it give error 
2011-04-06 15:37:24.232 logintes1[18130:207] *** Assertion failure in -[logintes1ViewController check], /Users/HarishYadav/Desktop/logintes1/Classes/logintes1ViewController.m:72
2011-04-06 15:37:24.243 logintes1[18130:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error selecting data: library routine called out of sequence'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: You should make sure, that the tableName and the attributes are written correctly, if there is one little misstake (for example with capital letters, since the query is case-sensitive), you can't execute the query as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Check the query itself, print it in log and check it by copying it from log and executing directly in the database.

Comment: it give me right results .for print in log i use               NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * from UserInformation where UserName='%@' and Password='%@' ",Username.text,Password.text];                                                      NSLog(@"%@",sql);

Comment: when i use Break Point on code .The BP when come the                if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &selectSatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) then it directly come out of scope

Comment: remove the where clause and try once again..and let me know... NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * from UserInformation"];